# Javascript - Detecting defined variable as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example:

```
var myObj = {
    yes: undefined
}

console.log(typeof myObj.yes === 'undefined') //--> true
console.log(typeof myObj.nop === 'undefined') //--> true too
```

Is there a way to detect if myObj.nop is not defined as undefined ?

Comment: Because type of undefined is undefined. Use `hasOwnProperty` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `in`:

```
if('yes' in myObj) {
  // then we know the key exists, even if its value is undefined
}
```

Keep in mind, this also checks for properties in the object's prototype, which is probably fine in your case, but in case you only want to check properties that are *directly set on that specific object*, you can use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty('yes')) {
  // then it exists on that object
}
```

Here's [a good article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html) on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hasOwnProperty`.

```
myObj.hasOwnProperty('yes');             // returns true
myObj.hasOwnProperty('nop');         // returns false
```

Comment: I was about to key it

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {
    yes: undefined
}

console.log( myObj.yes === undefined); // gives true
```

and

```
var myObj = {
        yes: 'any value here'
    }

    console.log( myObj.yes === undefined); // gives false
```

One thing to note here is that the undefined is not in single quotes. May be this gives you right direction.